# Using Microsoft Azure Query Editor how do you export data returned from a query as txt

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I am using Microsoft Azure for my web application (C#) which is using an SQL Database on there. I have a very important SELECT statement that I run so it can return some data for me. I need to save that data as a .txt file, **Text(tab delimited)** .

I ran the query on the database using the Query Editor inside Azure. The issue I am facing is that the Query Editor seems to only allow export it as .json, .CSV, .XML.
See image screenshot below, the dropdown does not contain .txt format.
[image]

How can I export that data as a .txt from this tool within Azure?

I can't copy + paste the results into a notepad file straight from the query editor because it does not come out formatted correctly, it needs to be in Text(tab delimited)

Currently the only way I have managed to find a work around is by having to use my actual local machine with SSMS SQL Server Management Studio to connect to the Azure database in the cloud and THEN I can run the query and SAVE AS a .txt (all from my local computer which has SSMS installed).

I can't do this when I am using a machine that does not have the database connection, I can't do this when I am on the road and do not have my actual desktop with SSMS installed... so it is important that I am able to log into my Azure portal and save the data in the file format I need straight from Azure itself...

Any suggestions on how to save as a .txt Text(tab delimited) straight from an Azure sql database?

Comment: It looks like you're generating a google feed? Why not automate your solution so you don't have to do this stuff every X days?

Comment: Yes correct it is a feed file for Google. I plan on automating that process but my skills are not quite there yet so I started off by just running the query and then pasting it to the location in my virtual location which then google crawls at midnight. Any suggestions on how to automate that using Azure?

Comment: Well, on your webserver you can schedule a script to bcp out the data you need and save it to file.

Comment: Ok thank you that is great information. I am going to look into BCP and try that out.

Answer (score 0):

I created azure sql database and created table inserted values into that to save the data I got .csv, .json, .xml format is available in azure portal

[image]

As per my knowledge we cannot convert result to text format in azure portal itself. As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/691225/i-want-to-run-sql-in-azure-studio-with-output-in-t)  Azure datastudion is also not supported for this operation. So I connected the database to SSMS

[image]

I executed the query which I want to convert into txt file
and right click on result I got below list I selected save result as option:

[image]

I got the file path to save the txt file named it to result.txt and saved it.

[image]

result.txt file:

[image]

By using SSMS I am getting perfect result of query as mentioned above. If you are unable to do with SSMS try with BCP command in command prompt:

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.product" queryout <filepath>test.txt -S <servername>.database.windows.net -d <databasename> -U <username> -P <password>
```

[image]

you will get result as below:

[image]

Comment: Yeah that is how I am doing it now with my SSMS on my local machine, but wanted to have a solution where I do not have to connect to my SSMS since I make edits to the feed when I am on the road and do not always have a computer with me that has SSMS. I wanted to see how to do it straight from Azure but looks like its not possible. As 
siggemannen suggested above though I have to find a way to automate this task from Azure.

Comment: Oh sorry I just re-read the BCP part of your post. Thanks! So I can BCP from the Azure portal itself? Or were saying from a local machine I can BCP into the Azure db and trigger that via command prompt?

siggemannen above mentioned BCP that as well so I will look into that for sure.

Comment: You can do that from azure portal also by using power shell.

Comment: Ok I did some research from looking into your suggestion and found how to get to the CMD and PowerShell prompts inside of the SCM in Azure. Do you know the correct syntax using PowerShell to query the database so it can write the output to a file location in the c:\home\site\wwwroot\results.txt ? I tried the CMD version but kept getting an error that says Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server(even though I am using SQL login I think). I looked up a solution for that CMD error but wanted to give Powershell a shot to see if that might work instead.